# rails get particular value from database data's group's sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, group-by, sum

Here I have a database table named DeliveryCharge. I tried to get get the values of overall weight for every method. For which I tried like this:

```
@a = DeliveryCharge.all.group("method")
@a_sum = @a.sum("weight")
logger.debug("-----------#{@a_sum}----------")
```

and it is giving this output:

```
-----------{"e-packet"=>6, "ems"=>482, "free-shipping"=>9999}----------
```

Which is good. But now I want output of only methods in an array and weights in a different array. like this:
["e-packet", "ems", "free-shipping"] and [6, 482, 9999]
For that I tried these two ways:

```
logger.debug("-----------#{@a_sum(:method)}----------")   
logger.debug("-----------#{@a_sum[:method]}----------")
```

Which are not working. Could anyone help me how to get output like I mentioned above?
And also I tried 
`logger.debug("-----------#{Array(@a_sum)}----------")`
from which I got: 
`------[["e-packet", 6], ["ems", 482], ["free-shipping", 9999]]---`
but need to get it like the way I mentioned above.

Comment: `@a_sum.keys` and `@a_sum.values` will give you exactly what you want

Comment: yes. Thank you bro. It worked. But if you would add this answer as an answer instead of comment I could mark it as accepted. Btw, really thanks for your help

Comment: No worries mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `@a_sum` is a hash, you can simply use the `.keys` and `.values` methods to access those items.

`@a_sum.keys` and `@a_sum.values` will give you exactly what you want!